# C# unit test with TestCase() attribute doesn't clean database/cache?

Tags: c#, database, unit-testing, nunit

Weird thing, hope you can help.

```cs
[TestFixture]
public class TestClass
{

    [TestCase(Size.Big, Color.Blue)]
    [TestCase(Size.Big, Color.Red)]
    [TestCase(Size.Small, Color.Blue)]
    [TestCase(Size.Small, Color.Red)]
    public void TestChunkAndRun(Size a, Color b)
    {
        using (new TransactionScope())
        {
            try
            {
                //Data generation + test
            }
            finally
            {
                //manually rollbacking, disposing objects
            }
        }
    }

}
```

With this code, i am executing the unit test 4 times with different parameters. The unit test generates some data for the test itself. In the database 'Size' is part of a unique index, so it has to be unique.

The problem is that (no matter in what order the tests are executed) the 3rd and 4th testcases are ALWAYS failed due to duplicate row in database.

If I execute the tests one by one, separately, they pass. Only when I execute them as one group (no matter which order) the last 2 fail. Even when I manually rollback the transaction. 
The weird part is that the tables are empty indeed before each test. Somehow the data is being kept inbetween the TestCases so that i get Duplicate error

Any idea on what's happening?

**Additional question**: what's the difference between selecting multiple tests and clicking 'run all' & running the tests one by one

Comment: I'm testing inside VS with resharper (which uses Nunit). It might be the code concurrency, because the test is big)

Comment: I misunderstood the word 'concurrent'. The test is meant not to be concurrent. I'm just wondering how it can be that the tests run successfully when each test is selected separately and executed. But fail when sequentially run as a group.

Comment: Comment about `--process=Single` is not correct. The `--process` option has to do with how and where multiple test assemblies are run, not with threads in a single test assembly.

Comment: For a good answer, we need more info about what your tests are doing... what's happening in those comments, whether your fixture has any state, whether you are using SetUp, OneTimeSetUp, etc.

Answer (score 0):

[This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14349512/unit-test-fails-on-run-all-but-not-on-run-selected-tests-with-all-selected) helped me with my issue.

There were some readonly fields that were initialized outside the methods. Upon moving the initialization to a [TestInitialize]/[SetUp] method, it worked like a charm.